# Fluent NHibernate: How to Map List<String>

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I know there are lots of questions about how to map List of strings using fluent nHibernate. I tried all the options I got. But still no luck.

My situation is as follows.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class FirstChild : BaseClass
{
    public string Parameter{get;set;}
    public IList<string> OtherParameter {get;set;}
}
```

The mapping file I am using is as follows:

```
public class BaseClassMap: ClassMap<BaseClass>
{
    public BaseClassMap()
    {
        Table("BaseClass");          
        Map(x => x.Name);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<string>("Class");
    }
}

public class FirstChildMap : SubclassMap<FirstChild>
{
    public FirstChildMap ()
    {
        Map(x => x.Parameter);
        HasMany(x => x.OtherParameter)
            .Element("OtherParameter ")
            .Table("OtherParameterTable").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

After that when I try to save an object of type `FirstChild`, it saves the value of `Name` and `Parameter` but nothing goes into `OtherParameterTable`.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?